# Sharepoint webpart Jquery

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-enterprise, popup

I am trying display confirm dialog box after submit and do the rest of the process i am using following code but i click confirm nothing is happening.

button :

```
<asp:linkbutton id="btnSubmit" runat="server" validationgroup="grpContact" cssclass="greyBtn" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"> Submit</asp:linkbutton>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=btnSubmit.ClientID %>").click(function () {
            var validated = Page_ClientValidate('grpContact');
            if (validated) {
                $("#dialog").dialog({
                    buttons: {

                        "Confirm": function () {

                            $("#<%=btnSubmit.ClientID %>").submit();
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                            return true;

                        },
                        "Cancel": function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                            return false;
                        }

                    }
                });
            } return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using **preventDefault()**
Here's an example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#<%=btnSubmit.ClientID %>").on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var validated = Page_ClientValidate('grpContact');
            if (validated) {
                $("#dialog").dialog({
                    buttons: {

                        "Confirm": function () {

                            $("#<%=btnSubmit.ClientID %>").submit();
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                            return true;

                        },
                        "Cancel": function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                            return false;
                        }

                    }
                });
            } return false;
        });
```

Comment: what should be in confirm button

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" OnClientClick="return showTermsAndConditions(this);" Style="height: 26px" Text="Submit" ValidationGroup="GrpSubmit" />
var confirmed = false;
    function showTermsAndConditions(obj) {

                $("#dialogTermsAndConditions").dialog({
                    height: 650,
                    width: 800,
                    buttons: {
                        "Yes": function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                            confirmed = true; obj.click();
                        },
                        "No": function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    }
                });
                return confirmed;
            }
```